# How can I specify LiveCode's exit code?

Tags: livecode

I'm developing a wrapper around some LiveCode server-side scripts. Is there a way to exit a LiveCode script and specify an exit code? Right now, even unparseable code is given an exit code of 0. I'm looking for something like the [exit to top](http://docs.runrev.com/Control-Structure/exit-to-top) control structure that will let me pass 0-255.

Here's a particularly painful example

```
$ cat test.lc
> #!/usr/bin/env livecode-community-server
  lakjreakl j3lkj4?KJ !$()U* @$)LFKDJ SKLmvnkl 32498*$#
  lkfj KJ# >J$? !*!$  kljflkjuia o1238

$ ./test.lc
> file "/home/ian/test.lc"
  row 2, col 11: Expression: bad factor (!)
  row 2, col 1: param: bad expression
  row 2, col 11: Commands: bad parameter (!)
  row 2, col 11: Commands: bad parameters (!)
  row 2, col 11: script: bad command (!)

$ echo $?
> 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the [quit command](https://livecode.com/resources/api/#livecode_script/quit) and its as yet undocumented exit code parameter which defaults to 0!

```
quit 1
```

Comment: Thank you. Just sent a support ticket to Livecode asking them to document this. This has been bothering me for quite some time.

Comment: Good work, it might also be worth seeing what they think about lc server exiting with a non-zero exit code if there was an execution error

Answer (score 1):

You could try the "return" statement. It exits the current handler and whatever follows is sent to the calling handler. I haven't tried it on server but I'm thinking it might go to stdout if there is no calling handler: return "104"

"put" without a destination always goes to stdout, so you could alternately use "put 104" followed immediately by an "exit to top".